# Importing node_modules into a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack, import, node-modules

I'm trying to develop a chrome extension that will be using an npm package, more specifically, 'yt-search'.

I have tried to go at this both manually and using some available tools such as [generate chrome extension](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-chrome-extension) and [extension-cli](https://github.com/MobileFirstLLC/extension-cli/), both of which are supposed to automate the process and add the capability of using node-modules.

However, when importing the module either with `import 'yt-search` or `require()`, I get an error - 'Unable to find module cheerio', which is a dependency of 'yt-search'. My guess here is that the build process is just importing the main module and none of it's dependencies.

I would love to provide a working example, but being a chrome extension environment, it's a bit hard to do so here.

Comment: have you checked whether cheerio is present in node_modules?

Comment: Yes it is. Installing yt-search also installed all of it's dependencies. Upon going to yt-search's src, and commenting the line where it requires cheerio, the error changed to not being able to find whatever the next imported module was.

Comment: How many source files end up in your build/destination folder? For example, is your entire project compiled into a single JS file, or are you splitting the modules into multiple independently loaded files?

Comment: I ended up abandoning this project for other reasons ( unfeasibility due to API limitations ), but the problem with Cheerio was that it can only run in a node.js environment, iirc, and not in the browser